# Fullcalendar and Google - Hour-long events around midnight do not appear?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have created a calendar for a number of events that span midnight and we are trying to show them in the day view. As I couldn't find any other way to have the calendar day view itself span midnight, I created to fullcalendar views, one for the current day and the next for a few hours following midnight the next.

It works great, however, for some reason a number of events that span midnight are not showing up at all! I've tried creating a test event that starts at midnight and that doesn't even work!

The page in question (is unfortunately now live): http://www.nmm.se/schedule

You can see an example of the problem on Saturday evening whereas the google calendar we are using looks as so:

[image: Google Calendar - (SAT)]

[image: Google Calendar - Past Midnight (SUN)]

And the fullcalendar is missing events:

[image: NMM Schedule]

**EDIT**

It appears that simply creating events between 00:00 - 03:00 also seem to have issues on their own regardless of spanning from the previous day.

I've created a test jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/waffl/jXU8L/1/

**EDIT 2**

I had to manually add events in the live calendar, so for the purpose of this problem I would refer to the jsfiddle in the previous edit. The google calendar it is using as a source can be seen here: https://www.google.com/calendar/b/0/embed?src=nmm.se_arr0v56v6piib6abvk5j7re6bo@group.calendar.google.com&ctz=Europe/Stockholm&gsessionid=OK

Comment: have you tried to set alldaydefault to false  http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/allDayDefault/  FC has some major issues with timezones and calcualting times. For example your fiddle shows test form 00:00 - 02:30 normally for me. ...? Can you add a time that goes from 22:00 to the next day 03:00.

Comment: @ppumkin Yes that event from 00:00-02:30 works, but for some reason events say from 00:00-01:00, or 23:00-01:00 don't work. You can see, there are a lot of other events in the google calendar that don't show up in the fiddle: https://www.google.com/calendar/b/0/embed?src=nmm.se_arr0v56v6piib6abvk5j7re6bo@group.calendar.google.com&ctz=Europe/Stockholm&gsessionid=OK - Unfortunately, allDayDefault didn't seem to affect anything?

Comment: Ok will look at that. it seems a bit strange whats happening - hopefully there is a simple solution